# Check For Free Variables

Tags: string, variables, haskell, substitution

Parse errors are currently my least favorite type of Haskell error. So I'm writing a function where I  get a list of pairs where the second component contains some variables (this is determined by `vars` which I previously defined in my code as `vars :: a -> [String]`. If the list is empty then there aren't any free variables and the substitution is considered solved.

I've done this but I'm getting a `parse error on '|'`

```
solved :: Subst a -> Bool
solved xs = null [(S(xs,d) | (S(xs,d)) <- xs, not (null (vars d)))]
```

I previously defined my data type as

```
data Subst a = S [(String,a)]
```

I despise parse errors because it takes forever to figure out whats wrong (lol). Any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
solved xs = null [(S(xs,d) | (S(xs,d)) <- xs, not (null (vars d)))]
                         ^^
```

there's a closing parenthesis missing.

But, it looks as though you have further problems,

```
data Subst a = S [(String,a)]

solved :: Subst a -> Bool
solved xs = null [(S(xs,d) | (S(xs,d)) <- xs, not (null (vars d)))]
```

`xs` is not a list in `pattern <- xs`, but a `Subst a`. Also you're shadowing the name `xs`, which makes the code hard to follow. You probably want something like

```
solved (S xs) = null [ () | (varname, d) <- xs, not (null $ vars d) ]
```

Comment: now I'm getting that there is no instance arising from the use of vars in `not (null $ vars d)`

Comment: Well, what kind of function is `vars`? I took the `null (vars d)` from your code. Maybe you need a context on `solved`, along the lines of `solved :: SomeClass a => Subst a -> Bool`.

Comment: yep you were right. can't believe i missed that. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the parse error because the `|` is inside a pair of parentheses - it needs to be directly inside the square brackets of the list comprehension to be syntactically valid.

After fixing that, you'll get a type error because your type signature says that your function takes a `Subst a`, but you're treating your argument like a list.

I also suspect that you'll run into problems with your `vars` function since there can't really be a sensible function of type `a -> [String]` (where by "sensible" I mean one that doesn't just return the same list of strings for every argument).